# Added Data On Other Page using ItextSharp

Tags: itext

this question, regarding to create pdf using itextSharp

I added table in document in that table first row i have added manually like Name, Id and so on and that table name and id coming from database now my problem is  that when page is over then again i want to add same manually row like Name, Id and data will be continue coming from database so what should i Do?? please help me out of these probs..

Answer (score 1):

It all really depends on how you are creating the documents.  Are you appending to an existing document, or are you generating a new document from scratch?  Either way, you are probably going to end up using `PageEvents` to accomplish this.  You can write custom `OnPageEnd`events to "rewrite" the table headers when the writer reaches the beginning of a new page.  if you are doing this from a "from-scratch" perspective, it could get tricky, but you should still be fine, as long as you fire the event **during** your table creation. IF you are appending to an existing document, it may be in your better interest to create a file containing the table(s), and merge them together after you finish making the table. It's not a particularly complicated process either way.  If you are creating your table within a for or while loop, like:

```
for(int i = 0; a < 100; i++)
{
    //OnPageEnd Event that adds the Table Header
    table.addCell(cell)
}
```

This way, for every iteration of the loop, it is checking to see if it has to write to a new page.  If it doesn't, it will continue adding cells.  If it does, it will insert your header row, and continue looping.

It should be really simple.  I usually create a class file containing my page events, and I call them as I need them.  Once you get the class file created, and create your function, it's as simple as adding in the code you use to write the headers currently to the Event.  Page Events seem much more daunting than they really are, but once you take a minute and read about them a little bit, you can save yourself a lot of headaches, and you can create much more dynamic documents.

Hopefully this points you in a good direction, as I had my own struggles with table creation, and handling page breaks cleanly.

**Edit**

---

I'll show you a simple method I use for creating let's say a 1 cell table for ease, but it's expandable to as many as you need.  This is assuming the position that you are creating a separate document for the table file, and merging them after. This isn't really a part of your question, so I'll leave it out unless you ask for more clarification on how to go about that.

```
private void appendTable(string inputFile, string outputFile, string id)
{
    Document outputDoc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 15, 15, 35, 50);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFile);
    string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='{0}'", id);
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = db.GetDataTable(sql);
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        iTextSharp.text.Font arial = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8);
        iTextSharp.text.Font arialheader = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12);
        table.WidthPercentage = 95;
        PdfPCell headerCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell Header", arialheader));
        headerCell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        table.AddCell(headerCell);

        PdfWriter wr = PdfWriter.GetInstance(outputDoc, new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite));
        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell Text", arial));
            meterCell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //Center Aligned
            table.AddCell(meterCell);
        }

        outputDoc.Open();
        wr.PageEvent = new PageEvents.Header();
        wr.PageEvent = new PageEvents.Footer();
        outputDoc.Add(table);
        outputDoc.NewPage();
        outputDoc.Close();
    }

    catch (PdfException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString() + " **** " + ex.StackTrace);
    }
    catch (NpgsqlException ex)
    {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString() + " **** " + ex.StackTrace);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank You so much Mike but what if it's last page and no record of table found ,only thanks words remaining in the document then also header will created on last page of my PDF, i don't want this last page header can you please tell me what should i do?

Comment: Sorry the reply took so long, I have been really busy with a new project.  However, I had to revisit this portion of it today, so it seemed fitting to spread what I've learned. I'll edit my answer to include the new scenario you presented me.

Comment: What this method actually does is create the whole table at once.  After it is finished, it tries to write it to one page if it will fit, but if the onpageend event fires, it knows a new page is required, so it will set that new page up, and continue where it left off writing the table.  An interesting thing to point out is the declaration of the Margins when you are making the inital document, and this addendum.  You will need to experiment to get it right depending on the size of your headers and footers, etc.  Cheers!